# Build Blackjack program in Java, but "split" method would require rewriting whole program?

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

Getting back into programming after many years, and build a simple "blackjack" program in Java.

I'm wondering if the way I structured the methods/objects is bad, using global static variables. The program seems to work fine, but there's no way to implement a "split" method without re-writing everything, since you can't pass the new "split" hands into the "hit" or "stand" functions.

I'm curious how others would structure this and what the flaws in my methodology were. Thanks!

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BlackJack {
    
    static int bankroll = 0;
    static int bet = 1;
    static int index = 0;
    static CardDeck d = new CardDeck();
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards2 = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards3 = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards4 = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards5 = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static ArrayList<Card> playerCards6 = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static ArrayList<Card> dealerCards = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused - was thinking of using for splitting
    static int playerScore = 0;
    static int dealerScore = 0;
    static String action = "";
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        initializeBankroll();
        
        while (bet != 0) {
            
            startRound();
            display();
            if(checkBlackJacks()) continue;
            
            while (playerScore <= 21) {
                
            System.out.println("H - hit, S - stand, X - surrender, D - double down");
            action = s.nextLine();
            if (action.equals("H")) hit();
            else if (action.equals("S")) {
                stand();
                break;
            }
            else if (action.equals("X")) surrender();
            else if (action.equals("D")) {
                doubleDown();
                break;
            }
            
            }
            
            eval();
        }
    }
    
    public static int score (ArrayList<Card> list) {
        int ret = 0;
        int acecounter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getVal()>1) {
                ret += Math.min(10, list.get(i).getVal());
            }
            else { //An ace
                ret += 11;
                acecounter++;
            }
        }
        
        while(ret >21 && acecounter >0) {
            ret -= 10;
            acecounter -= 1;
        }
        
        return ret;
    }
    
    public static void dealToPlayer() {
        playerCards.add(d.getCard(index));
        index++;
    }
    
    public static void dealToDealer() {
        dealerCards.add(d.getCard(index));
        index++;
    }
    
    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("PLAYER CARDS:");
        String playerCardString = "";
        for (int i=0; i<playerCards.size(); i++) {
            playerCardString += playerCards.get(i).toString();
            playerCardString += " ";
        }
        System.out.println(playerCardString);
        System.out.println("DEALER CARD:");
        System.out.println(dealerCards.get(0).toString());
        
    }
    
    public static void hit() {
        dealToPlayer();
        reScore();
        display();
    }
    
    public static void surrender() {
        if(playerCards.size()>2) {
            System.out.println("You can't do that");
            return;
        }
        bankroll -= (bet / 2);
        playerScore = 100; //surrender
    }
    
    public static void reScore() {
        playerScore = score(playerCards);
        dealerScore = score(dealerCards);
    }
    
    public static void stand() {
        try {
        System.out.println("DEALER DOWNCARD: " + dealerCards.get(1).toString());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while (dealerScore <17) {
            dealToDealer();
            System.out.println(dealerCards.get(dealerCards.size()-1).toString());
            reScore(); 
            System.out.println("DEALER SCORE " + Integer.toString(dealerScore));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        }catch(Exception E) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
    
    public static void doubleDown() {
        if(playerCards.size()>2) {
            System.out.println("You can't do that, hitting instead");
            hit();
            if(playerScore<=21) stand();
            return;
        }
        if( bet * 2 > bankroll) {
            System.out.println("Doubling for less...");
            bet = bankroll;
            hit();
            if(playerScore<=21) stand();
            return;
        }
        bet *= 2;
        hit();
        if(playerScore<=21) stand();
    }
    
    public static void split(ArrayList<Card> splitarray, int splitcount) { //INCOMPLETE. How to get this to work?
        if(splitarray.size()>2 || bet * (splitcount+1) > bankroll || splitarray.get(1).getVal() != splitarray.get(0).getVal()) {
            System.out.println("Can't split. Hitting instead");
            hit();
        }
        
        ArrayList<Card> s1 = new ArrayList<Card>();
        ArrayList<Card> s2 = new ArrayList<Card>();
        s1.add(splitarray.get(0));
        s2.add(splitarray.get(1));
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    public static void eval() {
        if (playerScore==100) { //indicates a surrender, and bankroll has already been adjusted
            return;
        }
        if (playerScore>21) {
            System.out.println("BUST");
            bankroll -= bet;
            return;
        }
        if (dealerScore>21) {
            System.out.println("DEALER BUST");
            bankroll += bet;
            return;
        }
        if (playerScore > dealerScore) {
            System.out.println("WIN");
            bankroll += bet;
            return;
        }
        if (playerScore < dealerScore) {
            System.out.println("LOSE");
            bankroll -= bet;
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("PUSH");
        return;
    }
    
    public static void newhand() {
        d.shuffle();
        playerCards.clear();
        dealerCards.clear();
        index = 0;
        reScore();
    }
    
    public static boolean checkBlackJacks() {
        if(playerScore == 21) {
            if(dealerCards.get(0).getVal()==1) {
               System.out.println("Even money? Y / N");
               String even = s.nextLine();
               if (even=="Y"){
                       bankroll += bet;
                       newhand();
                       return true;
               }
            }
            if(dealerScore != 21) {
                System.out.println("BlackJack");
                bankroll += (1.5 * bet);
                newhand();
                return true;
                
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Push - Mutual Blackjack");
                newhand();
                return true;
                
            }
            
        }
        if(dealerCards.get(0).getVal()==1) { //insurance
            System.out.println("Insurance? Type wager or 0, up to half your bet");
            int insuranceBet = s.nextInt();
            if (insuranceBet > bankroll) insuranceBet = bankroll;
            if (insuranceBet > (bet / 2)) insuranceBet = bet / 2;
            if (dealerScore == 21) bankroll += (insuranceBet * 2); 
            else bankroll -= insuranceBet;
        }
        
        if(dealerScore==21) {
            System.out.println("Dealer Blackjack");
            bankroll -= bet;
            newhand();
            return true;
        }
        
        
        
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public static void initializeBankroll() {
        System.out.println("Enter your buy-in");
        bankroll = s.nextInt();
    }
    
    public static void startRound() {
        newhand();
        System.out.println("Money remaining:" + Integer.toString(bankroll));
        System.out.println("Enter your bet");
        bet = s.nextInt();
        if (bet>bankroll) bet=0;
        
        dealToPlayer();
        dealToDealer();
        dealToPlayer();
        dealToDealer();
        reScore();
    }

}
___________________


public class Card {
    
    int val; //1 = Ace, 11 = Jack, 12 = Queen, 13 = King
    int suit; //1 = Club, 2 = Diamond, 3 = Heart, 4 = Spade
    
    public Card() {
        this(1,1);
    }
    
    public Card(int val, int suit) {
        this.val = val;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
    
    public int getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }
    
    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    
    public void setVal(int a) {
        if(a>=1 && a<= 13) val = a;
    }
    
    public void setSuit(int a) {
        if (a>=1 && a<=4) suit = a;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String valString = "";
        String suitString = "";
        String ret = "";
        
        switch(val) {
        case 1: valString = "A"; break;
        case 10: valString = "T"; break;
        case 11: valString = "J"; break;
        case 12: valString = "Q"; break;
        case 13: valString = "K"; break;
        default: valString = Integer.toString(val);
        }
        
        switch(suit) {
        case 1: suitString = "c"; break;
        case 2: suitString = "d"; break;
        case 3: suitString = "h"; break;
        case 4: suitString = "s"; break;
        default: suitString = "ERROR"; break;
        }
        
        ret = valString + suitString;
        return ret;
        
    }

}
______________________

public class CardDeck{
  
  Card[] deck;
  
  public CardDeck(){
    int k=0;
    deck = new Card[52];
    for (int i=0; i<13; i++){
      for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        Card c = new Card(i+1,j+1);
        deck[k]=c;
        k++;
      } 
    }
    shuffle();
  }
  
  public void shuffle(){
    
    Card[] deckCopy = new Card[52];
    boolean[] flags = new boolean[52];
    for (int i=0; i<flags.length; i++) flags[i]=false;
    int numConverted=0;
    
    while(numConverted<52){
        int num = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
        if (flags[num]==false){
          deckCopy[numConverted]=deck[num];
          numConverted++;
          flags[num]=true;
        }
    }
    deck = deckCopy;
    
  } //end shuffle
  
  public String toString() {
      String ret = "";
      for (int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++) {
          ret += deck[i].toString();
          ret += " ";
      }
      return ret;
  }
  
  public Card getCard(int a) {
      if (a<0 || a > 51) return null;
      else return deck[a];
  }
  
  public int getSuit(int a) {
      if (a<0 || a > 51) return 0;
      else return deck[a].getSuit();
  }
  
  public int getVal(int a) {
      if (a<0 || a > 51) return 0;
      else return deck[a].getVal();
  }
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: The [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern explains one way to create an application model using one or more plain java getter/setter classes.  Application design is often an iterative process.

Comment: Global statics are awful for this reason, among others.  There is basically never a good reason to have mutable statics.